# Finding closest neighboring capital with coordinates in time series data in R

Tags: r, time-series, coordinates, r-sf

I have an extensive time series consisting of the worlds countries observed every year. The time series is from 1789 to 2019.

The data includes the coordinates for what is the capital that year. I want to find the closes neighbouring capital and the distance to that capital. Keep in mind that the capital might change from year to year.

I have been able to find a solution, but it only works for one year at a time. Is there a way to do this operation automatically, so I don’t have to do the same thing 230 times?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

df_dist_1789 <- df %>% filter(Year == 1789) %>% drop_na(Longitude) 

df_sf <- st_as_sf(df_dist_1789, coords = c("Longitude", "Latitude"),
              crs = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")

dist.mat <- st_distance(df_sf) 

nn.dist <- apply(dist.mat, 1, function(x) { 
return(sort(x, partial = 2)[2])
})

nn.index <- apply(dist.mat, 1, function(x) {order(x, decreasing=F)[2]})
n.data <- df_dist_1789 %>% select(Contry_name, Capital)

colnames(n.data)[1] <- "Neighbor_Contry"
colnames(n.data)[2] <- "Neighbor_Capital"

df_dist_1789 <- data.frame(df_dist_1789,
                  n.data[nn.index, ],
                  Distance = nn.dist)

rownames(df_dist_1789) <- seq(nrow(df_dist_1789))
df_dist_1789$Distance <- as.integer(df_dist_1789$Distance)
```

Comment: Since you seem familiar with `apply`, what's wrong with writing a for-loop or using one of the `apply` functions?

Comment: The code you provide is not quite reproducible, and I can't make it run using your data - the "Here is the data" link has only country/capital pairs, no coordinates nor time dimension. So a general comment: consider st_nearest_feature, it will help you make the distance matrix one dimensional and easier to work with

Comment: I am not very skilled in R coding and I found this solution after many google searches. Therefore I am not familiar with the apply function. I will look at the st_nearest_feature function. The problem is that the closes neighbouring is sometimes the old capital in the same country. I am looking for the closes capital in a different country in a given year.